# How to merge several columns of the same dataframe?

Tags: r, merge

I have one big data frame containing different measurements performed by several probes.

The timing of the measurements are not exactly the same. As I want to compare both measurements at a given time and plot them in an animation, I need my data to be "synchronized".

Here is an example of the dataframe I get (in real life I have way more columns that I read directly from a text file):

```
time1.in.s <- seq(0.010, 100, length.out = 100)
time2.in.s <- seq(0.022, 100, length.out = 100)
data1 <- seq(-10, 100, length.out = 100)
data2 <- seq(-25, 80, length.out = 100)

my.df <- data.frame(time1.in.s, data1, time2.in.s, data2)
```

Which gives:

```
    time1.in.s      data1 time2.in.s       data2
1         0.01 -10.000000   0.022000 -25.0000000
2         1.02  -8.888889   1.031879 -23.9393939
3         2.03  -7.777778   2.041758 -22.8787879
4         3.04  -6.666667   3.051636 -21.8181818
5         4.05  -5.555556   4.061515 -20.7575758
6         5.06  -4.444444   5.071394 -19.6969697
```

What I want to do is merge the two timeX.in.s columns in a single "time" column. Where data is not available, I would have NAs that I could fill in with something like `na.approx(my.df$data1, x = my.df$time)`.

This code is given so that you can reproduce the problem, but in real life, time1.in.s, time2.in.s, data1 and data2 are not available separately. What I actually do is `my.df <- read.table(my.file, header = TRUE)` and I get the same result. I thus don't have the possibility to build the separate data frames directly, I need to split the one big data frame in several manually:

```
df.list <- list()
  for (i in seq(1, ncol(my.df), 2)) {
    df.list[[ceiling(i/2)]] <- data.frame(time = my.df[, i], data = my.df[, i+1])
  }
```

Then merge the dataframes one by one:

```
merged.df <- data.frame(time = as.numeric(NA), data = as.numeric(NA))
  for (i in 1:length(df.list)) {
    merged.df <- merge(merged.df, df.list[[i]], by = "time", all = TRUE)
  }
```

And finally fill in the gaps:

```
merged.df$data.y <- na.approx(merged.df$data.y, x = merged.df$time, na.rm = FALSE)
```

That definitely works (except the names of the columns are a big mess). But it is cumbersome and doesn't look very R to me. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Here is the result obtained with the above commands:

```
> head(merged.df)
      time data.x     data.y      data
1 0.010000     NA -10.000000        NA
2 0.022000     NA  -9.986799 -25.00000
3 1.020000     NA  -8.888889        NA
4 1.031879     NA  -8.875821 -23.93939
5 2.030000     NA  -7.777778        NA
6 2.041758     NA  -7.764843 -22.87879
```

Column data.x comes from the initial empty merged.df. It can be dumped.
Column data.y is the my.df$data1 column.
In the above dataframe, I did not use the na.approx command on column data (which corresponds to my.df$data2 column)

**Additional note on OmaymaS' proposed solution:**

To make this work in the general case (i.e. with any number of columns), what I have done is the following. First, I defined a 6 columns data frame:

```
time1.in.s <- seq(0.010, 100, length.out = 100)
time2.in.s <- seq(0.022, 100, length.out = 100)
time3.in.s <- seq(0.017, 99.8, length.out = 100)
data1 <- seq(-10, 100, length.out = 100)
data2 <- seq(-25, 80, length.out = 100)
data3 <- seq(-15, 70, length.out = 100)

my.df <- data.frame(time1.in.s, data1, time2.in.s, data2, time3.in.s, data3)
```

This leads to:

```
head(my.df)
  time1.in.s      data1 time2.in.s     data2 time3.in.s     data3
1       0.01 -10.000000   0.022000 -25.00000   0.017000 -15.00000
2       1.02  -8.888889   1.031879 -23.93939   1.024909 -14.14141
3       2.03  -7.777778   2.041758 -22.87879   2.032818 -13.28283
4       3.04  -6.666667   3.051636 -21.81818   3.040727 -12.42424
5       4.05  -5.555556   4.061515 -20.75758   4.048636 -11.56566
6       5.06  -4.444444   5.071394 -19.69697   5.056545 -10.70707
```

I changed the name of all columns containing the time to the same name (this way I don't have to tell the `merge` function which column to merge `by`):

```
colnames(my.df)[seq(1, ncol(my.df), 2)] <- "Time"
```

Then I loop on a slightly modified Reduce function:

```
df.merged <- my.df[, 1:2]

for (i in seq(3, ncol(my.df), 2)) {
  df.merged <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,
                                          all = TRUE),
                      list(df.merged,
                           my.df[, i:(i+1)])
  )
}
```

This gives:

```
> head(df.merged)
      Time      data1     data2     data3
1 0.010000 -10.000000        NA        NA
2 0.017000         NA        NA -15.00000
3 0.022000         NA -25.00000        NA
4 1.020000  -8.888889        NA        NA
5 1.024909         NA        NA -14.14141
6 1.031879         NA -23.93939        NA
```

Finally, I apply the `na.approx` function:

```
df.interp <- df.merged
df.interp[, 2:ncol(df.interp)] <- na.approx(df.interp[, 2:ncol(df.interp)],
                                            x = df.interp$Time,
                                             na.rm = FALSE)
```

Here is the final result:

```
> head(df.interp)
      Time      data1     data2     data3
1 0.010000 -10.000000        NA        NA
2 0.017000  -9.992299        NA -15.00000
3 0.022000  -9.986799 -25.00000 -14.99574
4 1.020000  -8.888889 -23.95187 -14.14560
5 1.024909  -8.883488 -23.94671 -14.14141
6 1.031879  -8.875821 -23.93939 -14.13548
```

I still have NAs at the beginning of some data columns, but I can get rid of them with the `na.omit` function.

Comment: could you provide the first 5 lines of your end result, because i cannot follow what you need with the code you provided.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try merge, it should help you accomplish what you need:

First: create two datframes with data and corresponding time:

```
df1 <- data.frame(time1.in.s, data1)
df2 <- data.frame(time2.in.s, data2)
```

Second: merge the two dataframes, specifying the column to use using by.x and by.y, and include all values:

```
df.merged <- merge(df1,df2,
      by.x = "time1.in.s",
      by.y = "time2.in.s",
      all.x = TRUE,
      all.y = TRUE)
```

**Note**: to clarify as per Sotos recommendation:

```
all.x = TRUE,
all.y = TRUE
```

is similar to

```
all = TRUE
```

So if you want to exclude values from either dataframes that do not exist in the other, you can set all.x or all.y to FALSE.

Now you will have time in once column, and you can rename the columns as you like.

```
> head(df.merged)
  time1.in.s      data1     data2
1   0.010000 -10.000000        NA
2   0.022000         NA -25.00000
3   1.020000  -8.888889        NA
4   1.031879         NA -23.93939
5   2.030000  -7.777778        NA
6   2.041758         NA -22.87879
```

**EDIT**: If you want to apply this on multiple columns, where you have multiple **timen.in.s- datan**, you can try reduce as follows, where you can add multiple selections in the list, and all will be merged according to the time column, assuming that it will be always the first in select.

```
df.merged <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,
                   by.x = names(x)[1],
                   by.y = names(y)[1],
                   all = TRUE),
   list(select(my.df,time1.in.s, data1),
        select(my.df,time2.in.s, data2))
   )

> head(df.merged)
  time1.in.s      data1     data2
1   0.010000 -10.000000        NA
2   0.022000         NA -25.00000
3   1.020000  -8.888889        NA
4   1.031879         NA -23.93939
5   2.030000  -7.777778        NA
6   2.041758         NA -22.87879
```

**Additional NOTE:**

If you want to use columns' indecies, you can use:

```
df.merged <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,
                                        by.x = names(x)[1],
                                        by.y = names(y)[1],
                                        all = TRUE),
                    list(select(my.df,1,2),
                         select(my.df,3,4))
)
```

Also **If your columns' names are consistent**, and you want to build the list automatically, you can create a function which takes an integer and return the columns' names you want to select:

```
getDF <- function(x)
{
        c1 <- paste0("time",x,".in.s")
        c2 <- paste0("data",x)
        return(c(c1,c2))
}
```

**For example:**

```
> getDF(1)
[1] "time1.in.s" "data1"
```

Then you can use this in reduce:

```
df.merged <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,
                                        by.x = names(x)[1],
                                        by.y = names(y)[1],
                                        all = TRUE),
                    list(my.df[,getDF(1)],
                         my.df[,getDF(2)])
)
```

Comment: FYI `(all.x = TRUE) + (all.y = TRUE) = (all = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos yes sure. I put it that way, in case someone is not familiar with it, it will be clear that one of them can be FALSE according to he need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not answer the question. This is basically what I have already done, except you do it on two data frames and I do it on any number of data frames... It is less cumbersome because you don't have the for loops, but in the end, you split the dataframes and merge them one by one.

Comment: @Ben so what you originally have is a dataframe with n columns, not separate dataframes, right?

Comment: Right, and I don't just have 4 columns as in the example, but way more (up to 40).

Comment: @Ben check the edited solution, it should help you as long as you have the columns in the required order.

Comment: The edited solution is very elegant, I like it. I'm trying to build the list automatically, without explicitly writing the name of the columns, but using column indexes instead to generalize the function to n columns. Will post update as soon as I found how to do it ;)

Comment: Thanks.
Check the additional note, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code.

I am assuming that you would like to split your `data.frame` every two columns

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

...
my.df <- data.frame(time1.in.s, data1, time2.in.s, data2)


my.df %<>% t %>% data.frame %>% 
           mutate(x=(mod(seq_along(row.names(.)), 2) + 
           seq_along(row.names(.)))/2) %>% split(., .$x) %>% lapply(t)

for (i in 1:length(my.df)) colnames(my.df[[i]]) <- c("time", paste0("data",i))

my.df %<>% lapply(function(x) x[-dim(x), ])

final = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), my.df)
```